# Outlook adding destination URL in square brackets after hyperlink in HTML e-mail

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, outlook, brackets

Bit of a head scratcher here, and I'm still waiting on some details.

The client reported that in Outlook, they are seeing the link in square brackets after the A tag.  This apparently just started with the most recent round of e-mails I did for them, but the link code has not changed.

Here is an example of a link :

```
<p style='margin-bottom:20px !important;' >
  <a href="https://www.fepblue.org/pilot/login" style="color:#005172; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;">Visit MyBlue to log on or register today.</a>
</p>
```

Here is an image of what they are seeing :
http://rweststaging.com/webmd_emails/example/example.png

I've tested in Litmus, and sent out test e-mails through MailChimp, and I'm not seeing that on any of the outlook versions.

I thought it might be some setting on their particular Outlook install, but they reported only seeing that happen on this particular group of e-mails.

Comment: Here's a link to the full e-mail, in case that is helpful :
http://rweststaging.com/webmd_emails/WebMD-ACQ-3-Content-Move-Shekers/email.html

Comment: Try to remove anything from HTML markup except the href attribute. Does it help?

Answer (score 7):

try to add `https://` to link in `<a>` html tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case part of the url was written with "\", I changed that to "/" and problem was solved-